# how to map maltivalue json into a table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am new to JSON and react development. So, I don't know the syntax of how to fetch this kind of JSON into the table or map into the table.
I am using Fetch API and the method is GET

[image]

Comment: what kind of json can you give some more information?

Comment: uploaded the json image

Comment: you want to create an html table using each admin?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Answer (score 3):

After fetching the JSON, set the hospitalAdmin to a State.

```js
    // response is the JSON that you Fetched
    setAdmins(response.hospitalAdmin);
```

After that, you can just Map over the Array of Admins in the return/render of your Component, like so:

```js
const AdminTable = () => {
    const [admins, setAdmins] = useState([]);
    
    // Code for Fetching Data

    return (
        <table>
            { admins.map((item) => (
              <tr>
                <td>{item.id}</td>
                ...
              </tr>
              )
            }
        </table>
    );
}
```